# Jupyter notebook python library testbook not giving any results

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, testbook

Here's my jupyter notebook's cell 1 (notebook is called tested.ipynb)

```
def func(a,b):
   return a+b
```

Here's the testbook testing python code (tester.py):

```
import testbook
@testbook.testbook('tested.ipynb',execute=True)
def test_func(tb):
    func=tb.ref("func")
    assert func(1,2)==0
```

I then run the following command from terminal:

```
python tester.py
```

It should fail the unit test. But I'm not getting any output at all. No failures, no messages. How do I make the failure appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you still need to use pytest, or another unit testing library, to run your tests. Note under 'Features' it says:

> "Works with any unit testing library - unittest, pytest or nose" -[SOURCE](https://testbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#features)

Testbook just makes writing the unit tests easier. See [here under 'Unit testing with testbook'](https://www.wrighters.io/unit-testing-python-code-in-jupyter-notebooks/) for an example of the process of using testbook in your toolchain with pytest, although bear in mind a lot of the syntax doesn't match the [the current documentation](https://testbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html#general-workflow-when-using-testbook-to-write-a-unit-test).  And so instead of running `python tester.py` from the terminal, run the following command from terminal if you've installed pytest:

```py
pytest tester.py
```

---

One thing I note, is that your import and decorator lines don't match [the current documentation](https://testbook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/index.html#general-workflow-when-using-testbook-to-write-a-unit-test). Nevertheless, **your code works when using `pytest tester.py`**. However, it may be best to adopt the current best practices illustrated in the documentation to keep your code more robust as development continues.